# Problem with “Export entries as CSV”

Tags: solspace-freeform, entries, export

I got a problem with “Export entries as CSV”
Few months ago, this one was working well. When I click it, I can get/download an excel file which contains all the entries.
Few days ago, I still could download excel file but it did not contains anything.
Now, I can download excel file but it shows something like ‘your storage is full’.

I think the database which stores the entries is full. But I asked the host guy and he said the database on my plan is unlimited. So my question is:

Is there an option to control the limitation for storage of database in expression engine (control panel) ?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your hosting accounts' file storage is full? Have you tired clearing ./system/expressionengine/cache/ ?

Comment: Hi @Greg, I tired control panel --> Tools --> Data --> Clear Caching --> and chose (clear) "all caches". That's not working. and I didnt find your path under ftp but i got ./core/expressionengine/cache/. I removed some but it's still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly, without looking at it personally, I can't tell for sure. I think this is a situation where we need to open a ticket for you and look further into it ourselves: support.solspace.com